# how to get MAC Address of bluetooth connected device in android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am sending an image via bluetooth in android and want to fetch the MAC address of Device to which the image is being sent.

Please find below my code.

```
private void bluetoothadd(){
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        // Device does not support Bluetooth

        Log.e("Bluetooth ","not found");
    }

    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivity(enableBtIntent);

        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        // If there are paired devices
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            // Loop through paired devices
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {


                Log.e("Mac Addressess","are:  "+mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(device.getAddress()));
            }
            }
        }

}
```

I am getting all paired device's MAC Address. I want the MAC Address of a device only to which data is being transmitted.

Comment: You want to find the address, when the other Device is connected to user's device, or even before the connection is established(Discovery Phase).. ???

Comment: i want the address of a other device when it is connected and i can get the MAC Address to which device the data is being sent.

Comment: check following links 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795424/how-to-get-the-bluetooth-devices-as-a-list

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471204/discovering-bluetooth-devices-listview-will-not-get-updated

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
```

Answer (score 1):

When the intent is fired to connect to the remote device and the device is successfully established the Device Address is returned as extra data with the Flag `EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS`.

You can check for the connection and establish it

```
if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
```

You can check the activity in  the on `onActivityResult`function to find the address like this

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE:
            // When DeviceListActivity returns with a device to connect
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Get the device MAC address
                 String add = data.getExtras()
                                     .getString(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
                address= add.toString();

                 // Get the BluetoothDevice object
                BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

            }
            break; 
}
}
```

This trick is used in the Bluetooth Chat Sample application you can find in the Examples folder of the SDK

Answer (score 1):

```
 private String connectedDeviceAdd = "";
 private BluetoothDevice connectedDevice;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    registerReceiver(this.mReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED));




 private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent
                    .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

            connectedDeviceAdd = device.getAddress();
            connectedDevice = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice(connectedDeviceAdd);

        } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Device Disconnected");

        }
    }
};



 @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(this.mReceiver);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So, it sounds like you want to get the bd_addr/mac of a device that you have a connection with?  Then note that the BluetoothSocket class has a member 'getRemoteDevice', which returns a BluetoothDevice instance representing the device you are connected to, on which you can call getAddress() to get the MAC.

Or you can register for ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED which contains 'EXTRA_DEVICE' that will lead you to a BluetoothDevice.

Answer (score -1):

This work for me:

```
String macAddress = android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(mContext.getContentResolver(), "bluetooth_address");
```

Answer (score -3):

Try it.

```
WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo info = manager.getConnectionInfo();
String address = info.getMacAddress();
```

Comment: No, that's wifi.  Though the use of the term MAC address is usually associated with wifi it can be used for a Bluetooth BD_ADDR too.

Comment: Mac address is only available with wi-fi module!