# Detect which BT device is going out of range

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, android-ble

Is there a way to check which device among the paired Bluetooth devices is out of range/disconnected? I am able to see that some device is going out of range but need to identify which device is going out of range.

Comment: Doesn't the API have a way to check the MAC addresses of the connected devices? I believe that's the case.

Comment: @marcman Apis just fire a disconnected intent but I dont see a way to get MAC of which device is going out

Comment: Doesn't [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32949889/3427580) show a way to get the MAC addresses of the connected devices? When a new device joins or leaves, collect the set of connected devices. Compare to the previous set and check which device is no longer present

Comment: @marman I will have to try this. I was looking for a way if BT Apis has a way to auto detect. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @marcman mentioned in the comments, comparing the list of paired devices before and after would help to see which device is going out of range.