# How to get the address/name of connected Bluetooth device - Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I need to get the CONNECTED device name and address.

This is what I have tried so far and with it I'm able to get the paired devices list and addresses.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  TextView mBlue;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mBlue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Bluetooth);

    String s = " ";
    BluetoothAdapter ba = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    Set <BluetoothDevice> devices = ba.getBondedDevices();

    if (ba != null) {
      for (BluetoothDevice device: devices)
        s += device.getName() + "-" + device.getAddress() + "\n";
    } else
      s += "No address";

    mBlue.setText(s.toString());
  }
}
```

> How to get the device address/name of connected Bluetooth device?

Please help me out with a clear code (both manifest and class code). I have seen other posts on SO but I can't make it out. Please help to solve this.

Comment: When you pair a device, you get its information: https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/apis/bluetooth#device-pairing additionally, check the Bluetooth documentation and search around, there are plenty of blog posts about using Bluetooth and I'm sure there are some libraries that make the APIs a little bit more streamlined with less calling back around.

Comment: Yes sir, I have gone through documentation and other stuff I couldn't figure out and moreover it's my first project on andriod so I came here for experts assistance or who already have good knowledge about that. Anyways thanks sir.

Comment: You can look into this project to get an idea - https://github.com/googlearchive/android-BluetoothChat

Comment: Also, you might consider seeing this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57352834/3145960